# How to enable Indications on Client Configuration descriptor from iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to get the notification from a bluetooth device upon the characteristic value change. For this I need to enable notification for Client Characteristic Configuration(CCC) descriptor. I have used `setNotifyValue(enabled: Bool, forCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic)` for the characteristic but not getting the update for value changes.

I tried to enable the indication for CCC using `writeValue(data: NSData, forDescriptor descriptor: CBDescriptor)` but my app crashes for this API and shows the error as

> Cannot write Client Characteristic Configuration descriptors using this method!

Any help!!

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? I also meet this problem. I dont know how to enable the Notification/Indication.

Comment: same problem. on android setting the CCC solved the problem of not receiving the indications but ios does not allow me to do that. Sole setNotifyValue does not work as it did not work for this particular characteristic on android as well.

Answer (score 1):

Provide more codes might help to imporove accuracy of an answer; however, let's be assuming you have already been able to discover all characteristic values. Usually you just need to  iterate all characteristics and set/write value according to each Client Characteristic Configuration(CCC) descriptor in `CBPeripheralDelegate` implementation.

An example is attached below:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error discovering characteristics: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {

        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBManager accelDataUUID]]) {
            [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
        } else if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBManager accelConfigUUID]]) {
            [peripheral writeValue:[CBManager switchData:YES]
                 forCharacteristic:characteristic
                              type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
        }
        //... if you have more to iterate
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm already subscribing like that. It works for all other characteristics except one. I'm starting to think it could be an issue with the peripheral.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the availability of the characteristic's notification.

[From Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH3-SW7)

> When you subscribe to (or unsubscribe from) a characteristic’s value,
>   the peripheral calls the
>   `peripheral:didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:error:` method
>   of its delegate object. If the subscription request fails for any
>   reason, you can implement this delegate method to access the cause of
>   the error, as the following example shows:

```
 -(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic
             error:(NSError *)error {

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error changing notification state: %@",
           [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    ...
```

> Note: Not all characteristics offer subscription. You can determine
>   if a characteristic offers subscription by checking if its properties
>   attribute includes either of the `CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify` or
>   `CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate` constants.